# Proper way to move Rigidbody GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning Unity. I tried to make a simple box move by using this script. The premise is, whenever someone presses 'w' the box moves forward.

```
public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;
private Rigidbody rb;


public void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

public void Update () {
    bool w = Input.GetButton("w");

    if (w) {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * speed;
        rb.MovePosition(move);
        Debug.Log("Moved using w key");

    }

}
}
```

Whenever I use this, the box doesn't move forward on a 'w' keypress. What is wrong with my code? I thought it might be the way I have my *Vector 3 `move`* set up so I tried replacing the z-axis with speed, but that didn't work. Could someone tell me where I am messing up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You move `Rigidbody` with [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and rotate it with [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) if you want it to properly collide with Objects around it. `Rigidbody`  should not be moved by their position, rotation or the Translate variables/function.

The "w" is not predefined like [SherinBinu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43714826/3785314) mentioned but that's not the only problem. If you define it and use `KeyCode.W` it still won't work. The object will move once and stop.

Change

```
Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * speed;
rb.MovePosition(move);
```

to

```
tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
```

This should do it:

```
public float speed;
private Rigidbody rb;


public void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

public void Update()
{
    bool w = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);

    if (w)
    {
        Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, I think you want to move your object with wasd key. If that's the case then use `Input.GetAxisRaw` or `Input.GetAxis`.

```
public void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
    tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
}
```

Comment: what is `tempVect`?

Comment: @RamonDias without the tempVect the object would only move once then do nothing. By adding the tempVect to the current position each frame, he creates movement.

Answer (score 3):

"w" is not predefined unless you explicitly define it. Use KeyCode.W

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;


    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update () {
        bool w = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);

        if (w) {
            Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * speed *Time.deltaTime;
            rb.MovePosition(move);
            Debug.Log("Moved using w key");

        }

    }
}
```

Use `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)` for getting input.
**EDIT NOTE**:
To move the object relative to its initial position use `rb.MovePosition(transform.position+move)` rather than `rb.MovePosition(move)`

Comment: Wont this move the object to the position move rather than moving the object relative to the initial position?

Comment: yes it will directly move to the position directly. if you want it to move relative to initial position then use `rb.MovePosition(transform.position+move)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `w` a bool, you can use axis, also, in unity editor you should make it so the rigidbody movement is frozen

here is some code

```
void update()
{
    rb.AddForce(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At year 2023, `bool w = Input.GetButton("w")` is OK now.

It would be much better if you move code in `Update()` to `FixedUpdate()`.
rb.MovePosition run in internal physics update, which takes place after each FixedUpdate().
If rb.MovePosition is executed in Update(), there is a great probability that several rb.MovePosition are executed but only one really does the job.
You may check [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

A rigidbody can be moved in serveral ways:

1. `rb.MovePosition` is OK.
       But you need to change rb.MovePosition(move) to rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move)
2. `rb.velocity = velocity` is a similar option.
       But you need to set it to zero if it is not moving.
   Both `rb.MovePosition` and `rb.velocity = velocity` move in a continuous way, which means the rigidBody may collide with other rigidBodys.
3. `rb.position = newPosition` is another option, which teleport the rigidBody from one place to another.

Answer (score -3):

bool w = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question asks for a way to move a rigidbody, and the answer you have provided doesn't directly answer it, and could be confusing to new coders. Please try to answer the question completely!

Comment: This answer is incomplete, doesn't answer the question, and is poor quality (doesn't come with any explanation).  This is far below the expectations of quality for answers I'd like to see on this site.