# ThirdPersonController moving stuttering when the character collider colliding with a cube collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move the player 1.5 distance to the player direction he is facing.
The cubes scale are 1,1,1 so i guess in logic the player should be falling between the cubes and this is another problem to solve i can make the cubes scale on Y to be 0.1.

But the problem now is that the player is starting moving forward but then he is stuck in the air stuttering.

```
private void MovePlayer(float speed)
    {
        player.position += player.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(player.position.x + 1.5f, player.position.y, player.position.z);
        MovePlayer(1f);
    }
```

[image: stuttering]

When the game is running the player keep stuttering all the time since he is trying to keep moving but getting stuck with the colliders.

Another problem related is in many case the player is in the air and looks like sitting instead standing on the cube. Only if i move the player a bit with the keys he is standing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible problems.

**1**.You did not disable `ThirdPersonUserControl` script. Note that the `ThirdPersonUserControl` script is attached to the ThirdPersonController GameObject. You must disable it, otherwise you will be moving the player from two scripts at the-same time.

[image]

**2**.`ThirdPersonController` uses `Rigidbody`. Do not move a `Rigidbody` object with the transform(`player.position`). You have to use one of the Rigidbody's functions such as `MovePosition`, `AddForce`, or velocity as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714781/proper-way-to-move-rigidbody-gameobject/43714922#43714922) post.

Since this is a `ThirdPersonController`, you shouldn't modify the `Rigidbody` directly. Use the `Move` function declared there to move it. You can pass the new position to the first parameter, then crush and jump value to the second and third parameter respectively. This must be done in the `FixedUpdate` update.

Example of moving `ThirdPersonCharacter` object properly:

```
ThirdPersonCharacter tpsScript;

void Start()
{
    GameObject tpsObj = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
    tpsScript = tpsObj.GetComponent<ThirdPersonCharacter>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Transform m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
    Vector3 m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
    Vector3 m_Move = v * m_CamForward + h * m_Cam.right;

    tpsScript.Move(m_Move, false, false);
}
```