# Any way of moving my player other then the controller script teleports

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I'm trying to make a spring wall in my 2d platformer. However every way I've tried to move my character (addforce, transform.translate and even tried using the bouncy naterial) teleports my character rather then moving it. This doesn't happen with my controller script. I suspect something in my script is causing this interaction but I'm not sure exactly what. Here is my controller script. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :))

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    //how fast he can go
    public float topSpeed = 15f;
    bool facingRight = true;
    //what direction character is facing
    bool grounded = false;
    //check if the character is grounded
    public Transform groundCheck;
    //the transform is used to see if character has touched the ground yet
    float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    //creates a ground radius for the transform circle for ground detection
    GameObject Player, Player2;
    int characterselect;
    //I'm pretty sure this stuff ^^ is unnessecary and is from when I had the character switch in this script but dont want to remove just in case
    public float jumpForce = 700f;
    //the characters jumpforce
    public GameObject jumpParticles;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    //what layer is the ground
    void Start()
    {
        characterselect = 1;
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        Player2 = GameObject.Find("Player2");
        //loads game objects as variables I'm pretty sure this stuff ^^^^ is unnessecary and is from when I had the character switch in this script but dont want to remove just in case

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //has the transform hit the ground yet returns a true or false value
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

        // get direction
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //add velocity to the move direction times by the speed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * topSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        if (move > 0 && !facingRight) //if facing not right then use the flip function
            flip();
        else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            flip();
        //the whole flip turned out not to be nesseary as my sprites were symetric

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if the character is in fact touching the ground then when space is pressed the function will run
        if(grounded&& Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //adds the jump force to the rigidbody attached to the character
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
            //Instantiate(jumpParticles, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //Destroy(jumpParticles, 3f);
        }
        {
            //this was code I was working on for character switching but couldn't get it to work properly. I didn't delete it because it took me ages to do and was recycled in the characterswitch script
          //  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
          //  {
            //    if (characterselect==1)
            //    {
             //       characterselect = 2;
              //  }
             //   else if (characterselect==2)
             //   {
              //      characterselect = 1;
             //   }
         //   }
          //  if (characterselect==1)
          //  {
            //    Player.SetActive(true);
              //  Player2.SetActive(false);
         //  }
           // else if (characterselect==2)
           // {
             //   Player.SetActive(false);
               // Player2.SetActive(true);
           // }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            topSpeed = topSpeed * 2;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            topSpeed = 15;
        }

    }

    void flip()
    {
        //for when facing the other direction
        facingRight = ! facingRight;
        //load the local scale
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        //flip character on the x axis
        theScale.x *= -1;
        //and then apply it to the local scale
        transform.localScale = theScale;


    }
```

Edit

```
      using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class boost : MonoBehaviour {
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

// Use this for initialization
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "booster") {
        Vector2 tempvect = new Vector2 (2, 0);
        rb2d.MovePosition ((Vector2)transform.position + tempvect);
    }


}
void Start () {
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

This is the code that I think should make it work the error comes at 
rb2d.MovePosition ((Vector2)transform.position + tempvect);

Comment: Use `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714781/proper-way-to-move-rigidbody-gameobject/43714922#43714922) for example. That's for 3d but you can easily modify that answer for 2D. Let me know if there is a problem

Comment: but I now get the error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
boost.OnCollisionEnter2D

Comment: Double click on the error and it will take you to where the error is on. Edit your question, add edit under it and add your new code. Also say where you are getting that error. Don't post a code in the comment section

Comment: Ok did that @Programmer

Comment: Rigidbody2D must be attached to the GameObject the `boost` script is attached to because without that `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` can't find it. By the way, I was expecting you to use that code I linked to move your player by replacing `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity` with it in `FixedUpdate` function from the `controller` script but I have no idea what you are doing now.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry forgot about that just trying to fix this error first because when I implemented the other code had the same error so just undid stuff trying to fix it because it wasn't there before. The script is attached to the player which is what contains the rigid body @Programmer

Comment: Oh I see now my question was way to confusing I'm trying to make a seperate script that pushes the player away on collision but it always ends up teleporting the player. I pasted my controller script because I thought that it might have something to do with whats causing this. The actual controller script works fine