# What does transform.TransformDirection(vector3.forward) * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to make a moving 3d character in unity and I stumbled upon a tutorial that told me to enter this line of code for when the user presses the "w" key and I don't know what the different components mean, could somebody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to move Rigidbody GameObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714781/proper-way-to-move-rigidbody-gameobject)

Answer (score 2):

Start to read the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html)!

- [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) is the [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) component attached to the same `GameObject` as this script is attached to.
- [`Transform.TransformDirection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html)

  > Transforms `direction` from **local** space to **world** space.
- [`Vector3.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html)

  > Shorthand for writing `new Vector3(0, 0, 1)`
- [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

  > The completion time in seconds since the last frame

  It is mostly used to convert any velocity from `units / frame` into a value of `units / second`.

So lets bring it all together:

1. You get the GameObject's `Transform` reference via `transform`.
2. You take the Vector `Vector3.forward` which equals `0,0,1` and use `transform.TransformDirection` in order to convert it to a worldspace forward vector of your GameObject.

   **Note: This is completely redundant and you shouldn't use this!**

   Rather directly use [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) which does exactly this already for you ;)

   > Returns a normalized vector representing the blue axis of the transform in world space
3. Finally you multiply this resulting vector by a magnitude. Currently it has a magnitude of `1` since it is a normalized vector so you want to use its direction but assign it a certain "speed".

   So you multiply it by `movementspeed` a predefined fixed speed value and use `Time.deltaTime` in order to convert it from a value of `movementspeed / frame` into a value of `movementspeed / second`

Answer (score -1):

The transform of an object is its position, rotation and scale.

Transform.direction is used to move the transforms position to a specified vector

Vector3.forward is a vector of x0,y0,z1

Time.deltaTime returns how many seconds passed between one frame to the next

movementspeed would be a variable that you assign with an int or float etc..

basically it moves the object this line is attached to forward by whatever your movement speed is per second