# How to collide two objects without moving either object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have a setup similar to [this mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4DP.jpg) in my 3D Unity game.

Each object has a collider as well as a rigid body. I am moving the object using mouse using simple mouse input events

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isSelected = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (!isSelected) return;
        Vector3 touchLocation = InputController.Instance.getTapLocation(); // Gets touch/mouse location using Raycast
        _transform.position = track.GetPositionOnPath(touchLocation); //Uses vector projection math
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (isSelected)
            isSelected = false;
    }
```

The object movement is constrained to a *path* using Vector projection

```
public Vector3 GetPositionOnPath(Vector3 touchLocation)
    {
        //Make the vector for the track u
        Vector3 u = end.position - start.position;
        //Make the touch location vector from the track start position v
        Vector3 v = touchLocation - start.position;

        float uv = Vector3.Dot(u, v);
        float uMagSqr = Mathf.Pow(u.magnitude, 2);
        Vector3 p = (uv / uMagSqr) * u; //Projection Formula (u.v)/(|u|^2) * u
        Vector3 finalVector = start.position + p;

        //Clamp the final vector to the end.positions of the track
        if (start.position.x > end.position.x)
            finalVector.x = Mathf.Clamp(finalVector.x, end.position.x, start.position.x);
        else
            finalVector.x = Mathf.Clamp(finalVector.x, start.position.x, end.position.x);
        if (start.position.z > end.position.z)
            finalVector.z = Mathf.Clamp(finalVector.z, end.position.z, start.position.z);
        else
            finalVector.z = Mathf.Clamp(finalVector.z, start.position.z, end.position.z);

        return finalVector;
    }
```

I want to make it in such a way that other objects in the way would obstruct the movement of the selected object as shown in the mockup. The solutions I thought of were to increase the weights of the objects so that they won't fly away when they collide, or to keep every object kinematic except the currently selected one. But they both have the same issue that the objects simply slide through each other.

It seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't seem to find any resources to help me out. I would really appreciate some help on how to tackle this problem and implement the mechanic as I intend. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can check for collision if it collide you can use freeze position in rigidbody2d constraints.

Comment: @ArtZolinaIII Hi. I actually considered this option. But even if the RigidBody's (I am using 3D. I will edit that in the question) positions are locked, I will still be able to move the object through the other object since it is being translated.

Comment: you can use [Sweeptest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html) and check if you *would* hit something before even allowing the movement

Comment: @derHugo Hi, This looks really promising. Thank you for this. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @derHugo I tried using the sweep test. But since the object is directly being translated, and the sweep test must have a short-range so that the object can get as close as possible, it is common for the object to move so fast that the collided object never comes within the range of the sweep test and start overlapping.

Comment: @AjilPappachan the sweeptest goes as far as you tell it to go ... Not only for short range ...

Comment: @derHugo Hi. Yes, I do realize that. But if I turn up the range too much then the collision is detected even when the object is too far away and stops abruptly even though there are no other objects nearby. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find the exact solution I am looking for. But since it is highly discouraged to move the position of a rigid body object, I switched over to a physics-based movement based on information I found on [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/924350/moving-gameobject-with-add-force-and-mouse-drag.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714781/proper-way-to-move-rigidbody-gameobject#:%7E:text=You%20move%20Rigidbody%20with%20Rigidbody,or%20the%20Translate%20variables%2Ffunction.) thread. Here is my current implementation:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isSelected = true;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if (!isSelected) return;
        Vector3 target = InputController.Instance.getTapLocation();
        //_rigidbody.MovePosition(target);
        force = _track.GetPositionOnPath(target) - _transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (!isSelected) return;
        isSelected = false;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        force = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _rigidbody.velocity = force;
    }
```

However, this comes at the cost of the movement not being perfectly responsive to the input given by the player as shown in this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwi8f.gif).

This is *a* fix so I am posting this as an answer but any other better options are much appreciated.

Comment: This implementation seems to be very unresponsive. The performance is okay but the movement lags behind the input quite a lot. I tried increasing the speed but to no avail.